# Is there any X11 font available both support English and Chinese?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, fonts

I need to display Chinese and English characters in the same line on an application. Is there any font for this?

Comment: You didn't give any details about the applications, but most applications today use libraries that have no trouble dealing with multiple fonts for different areas of the Unicode range. There are also quite a few pretty complete Unicode fonts, whicht at least include the standard Chinese characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try [otf-kopubworld](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/otf-kopubworld/) which was described as  "Multilingual (Korean, Yethangul, Chinese extended, Japanese, Latin extended, Cyrillic, Arabic, Hebrew, Devanagari) TrueType/OpenType fonts by the [Korea Publishers Association](http://www.kopus.org/Biz/electronic/Font.aspx)."